# Toggle in Jquery - can not close menu as expected

Tags: jquery

I have a problem to show and hide menus. When user clicks first time on "Show menu .." link, the menu should appear. On second click the same menu should disappear.

```
<p><a id="showmenu1" href="#">Show menu 1</a></p>
<p><a id="showmenu2" href="#">Show menu 1</a></p>

<div id="menu1" class="topmenus"> 
<div class="mystyle">
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="topmenus"> 
<div class="mystyle">
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I use toggle function of Jquery and it works OK.

```
$(document.body).on("click","#showmenu1",function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$("div.topmenus").not("#menu1").hide();
$("#menu1").toggle();
}); 

$(document.body).on("click","#showmenu2",function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$("div.topmenus").not("#menu2").hide();
$("#menu2").toggle();
});
```

But I also want to close all menus when user clicks on anywhere on the page. So, I added this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
if (!$("#menu1").is(e.target) && $("#menu1").has(e.target).length === 0) {$("#menu1").hide();}
if (!$("#menu2").is(e.target) && $("#menu2").has(e.target).length === 0) {$("#menu2").hide();}
});
```

Now the menu closes when I click anywhere on the page but toggle function doesn't work anymore - when I click second time on "Show menu ..." link, the menu does not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the clicked element is `.showmenu` by using `event.target`.

Here's a demo:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".showmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $menus = $(".topmenus")
  var index = $(this).index('.showmenu')
  var hidingTarget = $menus.splice((index-1), 1)
  $(hidingTarget).hide()
  $menus.toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('showmenu')) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(".topmenus").hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a id="showmenu1" class="showmenu" href="#">Show menu 1</a></p>
<p><a id="showmenu2" class="showmenu" href="#">Show menu 2</a></p>

<div id="menu1" class="topmenus">
  <div class="mystyle">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1-1</li>
      <li>Item1-2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="topmenus">
  <div class="mystyle">
    <ul>
      <li>Item2-1</li>
      <li>Item2-2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But there is the same problem as in my code - menu does not closes when I click second time on "Show menu" link.

Comment: I accept your answer, however on my website it does not work correctly - the first link opens both menus. The second links works correctly. And if I use image instead of tect "Shoe menu...it does not work at all. Works only woth text link. Something strange...